# What does phi mean in arima simulation

Tags: time-series, arima, simulation, autoregressive, parameterization

I'm learning time series and following [this tutorial](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/R_toot.htm)

When it comes to simulation, there are 2 types AR:

**AR1:** `x1 = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.9), n=100)`

**AR2:** `x = arima.sim(list(order=c(2,0,0), ar=c(1,-.9)), n=100)`

The value in `ar` is called phi. But I don't know what is it? In AR2, there are 2 values in `ar`, do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AR(1) model is usually written as:

$$Y_{t}=c+\phi Y_{{t-1}}+\varepsilon_{t}\,,$$

or in mean-corrected form as

$$Y_{t}-\mu=\phi (Y_{{t-1}}-\mu)+\varepsilon_{t}\,.$$

(For example, see Wikipedia's [Autoregressive Model - Example: an AR(1) process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Example:_An_AR.281.29_process). )

That symbol $\phi$ is "phi", and this is where the "phi" comes from in that list.

Similarly the AR(2) model is usually written as:

$$Y_{t}=c+\phi_1 Y_{{t-1}}+\phi_2 Y_{{t-2}}+\varepsilon_{t}\,,$$

or

$$Y_{t}-\mu=\phi_1 (Y_{{t-1}}-\mu)+\phi_2 (Y_{{t-2}}-\mu)+\varepsilon_{t}\,.$$

The two phi parameters there are why there are two values in `ar`.

(For example see Wikipedia's [Autoregressive model - Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Definition).)